# Apply Shadow to Button only bottom , left and right part in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, shadow

Below is my code : This code gives shadow to all part of button. I only want to give shadow to bottom part of button

Button should look like something like this :
[image]

```
var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.action(self.title)
            self.hover.toggle()
        }) {
            if title == "x" {
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "delete.left").cornerRadius(5).font(Font.system(size: 28, weight: .medium))
                    .background(Color..secondaryBG)
                    .accentColor(.accentTint)
                }
            } else {
                Text(title).customText(titleColor: .accentTint, fontName: .gothamMedium, fontSize: 28)
                    .background(Color.secondaryBG)
            }
        }
        .withBackground(color: .accentTint)
            .frame(width: 76, height: 76)
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .shadow(color: .numberPadShadowColor, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 1) // This gives shadow to all the parts. I do not want to give shadow to top part of button
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you show is more like a drop shadow with hard edges:

[image]

give it a solid background and shift it down:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            //
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "delete.left")
                .font(Font.system(size: 28, weight: .medium))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .frame(width: 76, height: 76)
        .background(Color(uiColor: .lightGray))
        .cornerRadius(5)
        
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 1)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ChrisR Thank you for the reply. I had attach the image in my Questions

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thank you ChrisR that works for me. Just 1 question - Is there any way we can color the offset instead black ?

Comment: I can do this but then it does add color to top corner also - 
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .background(Color.accentTint)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 1)

Comment: no, you do it the other way round and fill the background:
` .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(Color.accentTint)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 1)
        )`